# RF 433Mhz reciever not finding remotes

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, radio

I'm having some trouble with my 433Mhz receiver on my pi.

I first tried to read the signal my Nexa PET-910 and 433Mhz doorbell sent on the pi, but I could not get any usable data, just noise, or no data at all.

With the receive.py script from rpi-rf I got a lot of noise, and no signal when pushing both remotes. I then tried _433D from pigpio, and got nothing, then lastly I tried RCSniffer from 433Utils, also nothing. When I look in piscope I can see the signal getting picked up from both remotes(video of piscope picking up the Nexa remote: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpHsyVOz-hU).

I then tried RC-Switch(RecieveDemo_Advanced) on my arduino uno, and picked up the signal from my doorbell right away, so now I have the binary from that signal. However I could not pickup the signal from the Nexa remote on my arduino.

I can then use the binary from the doorbell remote signal and send from the pi to the doorbell and it rings. So I know it's the correct signal.

So now I have two questions. Firstly, I want to be able to send a MQTT message when my pi receives the signal from my door bell. The problem is I cant see the signal on any off the sniffers I tried. I can see it on arduino but not on the pi(same receiver).

The second question is what should I do to find the signal from my Nexa PET-910 remote?

Comment: `what should I do to find the signal from my Nexa PET-910 remote` more analysis of the signal you receive